# Wordpress Admin Jquery UI Sortable issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, wordpress, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm attempting to add the ability to drag and drop to reorder some boxes for a slider admin panel I'm modifying but I'm getting a very odd result when I drag and drop them

It seems to be moving the other elements down instead of moving the selected one.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".metabox-holder").sortable({
      //handle : '.handle',
      update : function () {
          var order = jQuery('.metabox-holder').sortable('serialize');
        jQuery("#info").load("process-sortable.php?"+order);
      }
    });
});
```

Here's the html: http://pastebin.com/dA3ygfTE

Please ignore the sloppiness of the html code - it is not my own.

Any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was an outdated version of jquery ui the code i ended up using is

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".metabox-holder").sortable({
      connectWith: '.metabox-holder',
    update: function() {
      var i = 1;
      jQuery('.postbox').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('h3 span').html('Image #'+i+'Link:');
        jQuery(this).find('input:first').attr('name', 'sImg'+i);
        jQuery(this).find('input:last').attr('name', 'sImglink'+i);
                i++;
      });
    }
    });
});
```